# In an RPM spec file, when a file isn't found, how to find out which %files line is at fault?

Tags: rpm, specfile

I'm working with a very macro-heavy RPM spec file, and when building it's producing an error I can't seem to track down:

```
File not found: /var/tmp/pkgnamehere/mockbuild/usr/com/pgsql
```

(I've replaced the full package buildroot path with "pkgnamehere" above, but it's otherwise unedited).

There's no `/usr/com/pgsql` anywhere in %files, nor in fact any `/com/` at all.

Presumably this is the result of macro expansion. The trouble is ... how does one find out which `%files` line corresponds to a given missing file? It doesn't say "File from %files on line 554 not found: " or anything useful like that.

The many of the actual `%files` lines look like:

```
%config(noreplace) %{_initrddir}/%{oname}-%{majorversion}
```

so a simple text search isn't useful here.

It's possible to `rpm --eval` each line, but that's pretty painful with over 300 files lines and the need to define all the input macros.

Tips?

```
$ rpm --version
RPM version 4.11.2
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-ia32:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-ia32:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
Release:        20
Codename:       Heisenbug
$ mock --version
1.1.41
```

---

Courtesy of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901349/398670), `rpmspec -P` will expand and print out a spec. However, it hasn't shed any light:

```
$ rpmspec -P unified-rpm/postgresql94.spec | grep '/com/'
$
```

in that there seems to be a mystery file here.

---

Courtesy of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901349/398670), `rpmspec -P` will expand and print out a spec.

It looked fine on the build machine - then I figured out it was actually an issue within the CentOS 5 `mock` sandbox.

There there's no `rpmspec`, so it's not easy to tell what's up. However [I stumbled over this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=894903) which suggests that it's an issue with RPM on RHEL5. Sure enough, in the sandbox:

```
<mock-chroot>[root@ayaki BUILD]# rpm --eval '%_sharedstatedir'
/usr/com
```

to which I say .... what!?

So the immediate issue can be worked around with:

```
%if 0%{rhel5}
%define _sharedstatedir /var/lib
%endif
```

or perhaps:

```
%if "%{_sharedstatedir}" == "/usr/com"
# See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=894903
%define _sharedstatedir /var/lib
%endif
```

... but anyway, the underlying question remains: How do you get RPM to tell you which `%files` line corresponds to a missing file?

Comment: It looks like the immediate issue might be https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=894903 - even though I'm on Fedora 20, it's apparently being hit in a RHEL5 mock build sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not Fedora 20, nor is it Mock. It's RHEL 5.

The RPM macro `%{_sharedstatedir}` was set to `%{prefix}/com` in both RHEL 4 and RHEL 5. The problem is that the macro was never used to build those distributions, so nobody paid any attention to its value. It only became an issue [when people began backporting packages](http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/10/rpm-building-fedoras-sharedstatedir.html) from later Fedora which did use the macro.

And, of course, because RHEL is a "stable" enterprise distribution which aims to not break compatibility during its lifecycle, this will never be changed.

The macro works as you expect in RHEL 6 and 7.

If you still have to support RHEL 5 boxes, you (and everyone else) are stuck with workarounds like the ones you already proposed. The simple and clean one is the first one you suggested:

```
%if 0%{rhel5}
%define _sharedstatedir /var/lib
%endif
```

I don't see any point to referencing that particular bug, since it doesn't actually explain the problem, nor give a workaround.